# Angle of ring pull with opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I want to know the angle of ring pull, but I can't do that yet.

Any ideas for doing that with opencv Python?

[image: Photo]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I put a photo to clarify my question, the angle is the yellow line and i want to detect with a camera this angle with a program in opencv python.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and use `HoughLinesP()` to try and spot that line, then calculate the angle from the line. That could then be passed to `ndimage.rotate()` if you need to rotate the image:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math
from scipy import ndimage

img_before = cv2.imread('find_angle.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_before, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_edges = cv2.Canny(img_gray, 100, 100, apertureSize=3)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(img_edges, 1, math.pi / 180.0, 100, minLineLength=80, maxLineGap=5)

angles = []

for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines[0]:
    cv2.line(img_before, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 3)
    angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1))
    angles.append(90 + angle)

median_angle = np.median(angles)
img_rotated = ndimage.rotate(img_before, median_angle)

cv2.imshow("Result", img_rotated)   
key = cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imwrite('rotated.jpg', img_rotated)
```

This would give you an output image of using an angle of `11.876`:

[image: rotate ring pull]

This approach though would need further tweaking for other images.

Comment: I put the lines for explain the problem, but in reality this lines are not in the image. I want to do a real time angle calculation of ring pull, then I tried for example do a hough circles but i have a lot of false positives, i calculated the angle with the slope of the line beetwen circles of the ring pull. 

Thanks for your answer !!

Comment: I drew the blue line to show what HoughLines was detecting. The image I used did not contain your lines (I had to remove them by hand to test with). I agree, this can produce wrong matches. Changing the `200` in Canny can help.

Comment: ah ok! i have wrong matches with this code, for example: 
 https://imgur.com/1gmpqXX      Can I do a solution with this algorithm? I have others forms too for example https://imgur.com/SNojsZ7

Comment: I am trying haar cascade but I can not do it yet

Comment: Possibly yes. One improved though would be to reduce Canny to 100 and get more lines, then take the median angle. I have updated it.